# 2 relationships between 2 entities in ER diagram

Tags: database, database-design, entity-relationship, database-schema

I'm trying to draw an ER diagram describing the following:

-"Department" employs "Employees"

-Some "Employees" are "Special" and have more attributes

-Some of the "Employees" ("Special" and non special) are "Managers"

-"Managers" manage "Departments"

So, to convey this I have:

```
Department ------(employs)------- Employee-----<--------Special
      |                             |
      |-----------(manages)----------
```

From my understanding, I cannot have 2 relationships between 2 entities. How do I deal with this situation then?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

There is no reason you can't have multiple relationships between the same two entities, your understanding is wrong in this respect.

You have to be certain, of course, that the relationships capture different information and that you haven't, say, mistaken the two aspects of a single relationship as two different relationships.  Your example seems to be a good candidate for having two relationships between the two entities.

Answer (score 4):

[image: Database Diagram]

Hi mate watch this diagram, hope it helps

Comment: This solution is acceptable only if a `Department` can have multiple `Employee` as managers.

Answer (score 4):

[image: Diagram] Better approach is to add a bit field in Employee table IsManager, so if he is a manager, that means that he is a manager on department he works.

Comment: This approach doesn't allow for an employee to manage a department unless (s)he is also in that department, and it also allows more than one employee to be a manager in the same department.

Comment: check out my other answer below

Comment: hey what software are you using for making the diagrams?

Comment: @el-aasi I'm using Sql Management Studio. Watch this https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=wMbPRHeYvMU

Answer (score 1):

Your relationship for employs and manages are going to be two linking tables. e.g. Consider the tables and fields as below:

```
Department
   DepartmentID
   DepartmentName

Employee
   EmployeeID
   EmployeeName

SpecialEmployee
   EmployeeID
   Attr1
   Attr2
```

Now you can go on and link Employee and Department as such:

```
DepartmentEmploys
     DepartmentEmploysID
     DepartmentID
     EmployeeID


ManagesDepartment
     ManagesDepartmentID    
     EmployeeID
     DepartmentID
```

Now your relationships do not overlap or interfere. What seems to be drawn in your diagram is correct. There can be more than one relationships between two entities.

Comment: Your first linking table is not *required*. The `DepartmentID` in `DepartmentEmploys` can simply be a FK in the `Employee` table. Also, the second linking table is acceptable only if a `Department` can have *multiple* `Employee` as managers.

Answer (score -1):

There should be only one class of employee If you have multiple categories of the employee then you can make child classes of Employee Class.
Parent: Employee
1st child: Special Employee
2nd child: Normal Employee

Comment: That does not solve the problem of having two relationships between the same entities and therefore does not really answer the question. But otherwise this looks like a better way to model the employee.